# Is the MacBook designed to hang from its display?

Tags: macbook-pro, accessories

I am looking admiringly at [the roost](http://www.therooststand.com/collections/the-roost-january-2014/products/the-roost-all-black) for my 17" MacBook Pro.

The height to which the MacBook is raised is terrific—[higher](http://www.overstock.com/Office-Supplies/Handstands-Monitor-Laptop-Stand/4072929/product.html) [than](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Portable-Folding-Laptop-Table-Stand/dp/B004JHTELG/) [any](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00466ND4E) [other](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002LNVMIS) [solution](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000TZTPQ6) [I'm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001EMA80) [able](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003GEJ5J4) [to](http://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?cPath=710_380_387&item_id=42215K) [locate](http://www.canadacomputers.com/product_info.php?cPath=710_380_382&item_id=046368) [online](http://www.ecofriend.com/eco-diys-laptop-stand-made-from-repurposed-cardboard.html) ([also](http://www.lcdarms.com/) [here](http://www.amazon.ca/Pyle-PLPTS25-Laptop-Computer-Stand/dp/B004HJ1ZB8/ref=pd_sim_sbs_ce_19) [and](http://www.amazon.ca/Pyle-PLPTS26-Laptop-Computer-Storage/dp/B004HJ5FSW/ref=pd_cp_ce_1) [there](http://www.ikea.com/ca/en/catalog/products/40148622/)). The promise of less strain on my neck is appealing. Since I'm looking for a portable solution (hence three phone books do not do the trick), the roost's weight is also appealing.

My problem is that this device does not **seat** the laptop. It **hangs** it from its display. I am not particularly tempted to pick up my mac from its display, nor to pick it and then let it hang there for hours on end. I suspect there will be considerable strain on the hinges, and I can already feel a minor bump where my thumb, ever so gently, opens the display, from merely the pull of the magnets, not to mention the potential damage to the screen (a single replacement part from Apple).

Is there any specification from Apple that the MacBook Pro is designed to withstand its own weight (6.6 lb; 3 Kg) through its display and hinges? Is doing so counter-specified? Lacking either, have you actually hung your 6.6-lb laptop from this device since its introduction in early 2014? Did the display survive?

**Update** Hooray! There is a [new design](http://www.therooststand.com/collections/roost-laptop-stand-pre-order/products/roost-laptop-stand).

**Update2** There is a [worthy](http://www.apple.com/ca/shop/product/HGXE2LL/A/rain-design-ilevel2-stand-for-macbook?fnode=8a) competitor in the field, but it's not portable.

Comment: It definetly looks like it's sitting on the stand

Comment: @soulshined There are wedges that fit between the base of the laptop and the screen that hold the laptop in place on the stand. There is nothing at the bottom (lower) edge of the laptop stopping it from sliding. It essentially "hangs", with all of the weight being supported by the lid of the laptop.

Comment: Ahh I see now, I think it just comes down to personal perspective. Check amazon or elsewhere for reviews on the product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would venture that this is not an endorsed way of mounting a laptop.  Holding an LCD by its housing can cause potential problems with the hinges, as well as pressure marks.  It's also possible to crack the metal as it's really thin around the screen.

Any sort of damage resulting from the use of such a device would most likely be deemed accidental and not covered by your warranty.

You should ask Apple what their official policy is if you're hell-bent on using this.